# Naming conventions in C# - Global Variables

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I know there is a debate/opinion about using `this` keyword or underscore in regards to private fields/properties (and I'll mention, I'm stuck on .NET 2.0)

Personally, I prefer `this`, but there are times you can't use it, for example when you need to reference a global variable from within a static method. Well, then we are forced to use the underscore (assuming we only have 2 choices, `this` or underscore). This means if my class uses any static methods I can't use `this` throughout the document.

Now, I've read the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28VS.71%29.aspx) and used [StyleCop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/documentation), both would rather I don't use the underscore, but my Resharper pretty much insists on using _.

I don't feel it is right to have one class use the _ and the next class use `this` simply to accommodate for when the classes mixes non-static and static methods! The advice here on SO is to keep to one implementation/style but I don't know if that means I should ignore Microsoft (and I know MS don't always follow their own rules)!

It has been suggested to prefix with something else, similarish to Hungarian but prefix with globVariableName where glob indicates global. I hate this idea, it's too bespoke and won't be obvious to any other developer outside my team.

So, my question is, what is the best way to define global variables consistently? Since they are naming guides, may be I can just ignore (at least _ can be used consistently but it feels wrong to ignore the advice from the language creators).

Comment: In C++ `m_` was the 'convention', convention in the losest sense of the term...

Comment: With 'global variable', I guess you mean a protected or private variable that is `static` or `const`. If that's the case, they go with PascalCase, if they are private/protected they should not. I don't see any conflict there.

Comment: I don't see how this can't turned into an extended discussion. I suggest asking this question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ since you don't have a **specific** question about your own code.  I have to question your class design if you have to have variable to reference an object within a static method.  Seems to be the static method should a variable name that describes any valid object.  **In other words perhaps using a global variable in a case like this is the entire problem.**

Comment: I've never used it myself, but isn't there a `global` keyword for global variables?

Comment: This should go on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) or [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: -1. I flagged not constructive, this is likely to generate a debate , not in a Q&A fashion.

Comment: Erm, wait, surely Resharper only insists on underscores for *private* fields?   The opposite of globals?  Create a static class named Globals.  Always write Globals.Name in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the class name in the same way you'd use "this", in a static class. Example follows:

```
public static class MyStatic
{
    public static object Global;

    public static void SomeMethod()
    {
        var theGlobal = MyStatic.Global;
    }
}

public class MyNonStatic
{
    public object Global;

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        var theGlobal = this.Global;
    }
}
```

Note: I can't actually think of any other way to do it.

Comment: type names should go in PascalCase.

Answer (score 1):

By global variables, I assume you mean `const` or `static` fields

I thing StyleCop used to encourage you to use `ClassName.staticField` for `static` and `const` fields, but it seems to have dropped that rule, at least by default. That is still a nice way to do it though.

Also, you can configure Resharper to play nicely with StyleCop.

Answer (score 0):

this is just my personal opinion;

- I believe using `this` for every private variable is very useful; it has a positive effect on readability of the code. Also, when you are employing some DI constructor injection method, it enables you to use same variable without any confusion, which seems very proper.

  ```
  public void SomeMethod(int someVariable)
  {
      this.someVariable = someVariable;
  }
  ```
- I prefer `this` instead of underscore; underscore seems pretty at first glance; but refering to the previous examples it has negative effect on readability.
- I name static variables with the same way I name class variables; usage of `this` keyword lowers the risk of confusion between private and static variables.

Answer (score 0):

I always use underscore for both static and instance variables.

For instance variables i use `this.variable`

For `static` variables i , sometimes, prefix them with the name of class, e.g., `ClassName.variable`